# i try to run the command "sudo apt update" on my linux and it showing the error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mern

```
E: Type 'mongodb-org/4.2' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/some-ppa.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

how i can solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Clean the current faulty mongo repo:

   rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list
2. Update :

   apt update
3. Follow the official instructions here:

   https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: first error is solved, but second line is remaining the same

Comment: Some-ppa do not seems to be mongo , what is ir?